# Using a list in my ObjectDataSource on my report for the DataSource of a Telerik Chart in report

Tags: datasource, objectdatasource, telerik-reporting, telerik-charting

Hey there I'm trying to use a list (Loans) within my ObjectDataSource (objectDataSource1) object on a report, as the DataSource for my Telerik chart on the same report. The majority of the tutorials I have looked at all show the report querying their database with a SQL string. I feel I'm over looking something silly. I've also posted on Telerik and haven't got a response quite yet.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
chart1.DataSource = objectDataSource1.Loans;
```

Or to be able to just set it at run time, as I'm doing with the other reporting tools on the report:

```
[=Fields.CurrentModel.Loans]
```

Is it possible to use a list within an ObjectDataSource as the DataSource for my Chart? Hopefully this is clear. Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after looking a bit deeper into it, I found this post on telerik's forums:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/build-chart-with-object-data-source.aspx

The charts themselves have "Bindings" where you can set up an expression where you can set the chart's DataSource property to a list on your Object Data source.

Going to the chart's Properties column and click the ellipse button under Bindings:
[image]

And from there just set the Property Path and the Expression and you're golden

[image]