# Telerik Reporting not showing data for the List Component

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

what I'm trying to accomplish is to show some data inside a Telerik List, but I can't understand what's wrong with my code.

To be more specific, my DataSource is in this way:

```
public class SalesReport
{
   ...
   public Tax Tax{ get; set; }
}

public class Tax
{
   ...
   public List<decimal> Values { get; set; }
}
```

There's a DataSource also, pointing to my SalesReport class.

I'm using the report in Design Mode and I have a List Component.
In this list, I've set up the DataSource property with my DataSource and also, I've set up the Binding property, pointing to the related field (e.g. = Fields.Tax.Values), just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485241/using-a-list-in-my-objectdatasource-on-my-report-for-the-datasource-of-a-telerik) and [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/details/how-to-databind-to-collection-properties).

As far as I know, these are the properties that is needed to be set up, but I can't figure out why the data is not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't get the solution with the List Component, I've changed to a Table component, connected the bindings and It's working now.